# How to add bandwith limiter to Linksys WRT54G (for Free)

Tags: router, bandwidth, firmware, wrt54g

I need a way to limit the bandwidth for certain IPs, or just limit the total bandwidth served through the wireless.

Is there a way to add this feature to this router? I have the following firmware:

```
Firmware Version:   v8.00.8 build 001, Oct. 5, 2009
```

Or maybe there is an alternative FREE firmware or something that will give such functionality?

UPDATE: On the back it says: Model No. WRT54G V8

Comment: [Which WRT54G](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linksys_WRT54G_series#Hardware_and_revisions) do you have?

Comment: Question updated.

Comment: Unfortunately, your options on that version are quite slim. It has only 2MB of flash -- not enough for a comfortable installation of most alternative firmwares.

Comment: But DD-WRT and OpenWRT claim to be compatible with WRT54G V8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com) is your answer.  It turns your WRT into a full featured router with QOS, VLANs, etc.  This [article](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Quality_of_Service) explains some of the QOS features.  You might also look at the [TC command](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Tc_command) to limit bandwidth

Answer (score 0):

One option is to replace your WRT54G firmware with a custom one like the ["special version" of DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/What_is_DD-WRT%3F#Special_Versions) which enables per-MAC bandwidth throttling:

> Currently brainslayer offers a special version of DD-WRT with extended
>   QoS capabilities:
>
> - set maximum bandwidth available per netmask/MAC address (v.24-SP1: even for different vlans)
> - set a default rule for any unconfigured netmask/MAC address

[image: DD-WRT Special QoS version]

I don't believe the regular version of DD-WRT will do what you want in the QoS, but you can certainly check it out and try it.  Otherwise this 'special version' is 20 Euros and you can get it at their shop [here](http://www.dd-wrt.com/shop/catalog/product_info.php?manufacturers_id=&products_id=31).

> **DD-WRT V24 Special**
>
> Our special DD-WRT standard/micro distribution which includes an additional PPPOE-Relay (standard only), Per User Bandwith
>   Control and Zero IP Hotspot. In the beginning this version was mainly
>   designed for WRT54Gv5/v6 and WRT54GS v5/v6 routers.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm looking for something free.

Comment: Well try the free version, and if it does what you want (perhaps using extra scripting) then you are off to the races. Otherwise, you may have to bust out a few dollars to get the higher-end routing capabilities you want from your $50 router. :)

Comment: So, do you think the free version doesn't have bandwidth management? I've been googling a little bit, and found OpenWRT. Have you heard of it?

Comment: @emzero Yup, but I've never used it. [Here's a list of about 10-20 various custom router firmware projects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_wireless_router_firmware_projects).  Perhaps check into a few of those, and/or give some time for more answers to be posted here?